# Excel SUM function for currency

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula

The cells I want to sum are:

```
A1 =DOLLAR(10.45)
B1 =DOLLAR(10)
```

When I use the SUM function:

```
=SUM(A1+B1)
```

It works, giving me 20.45. But If I do:

```
=SUM(A1:B1)
```

I get a #VALUE! error.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the behavior different between the two formulas? Why does making it a range change the way the cell values are interpreted?
2. Is it possible to write a function that uses a range to SUM dollar amounts?

Comment: it depends how you have formatted your dollar row? what do you see in the formula bar when you click on the A1?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using where `=SUM(A1:B1)` (where both A1 and B1 are text) returns #VALUE! and not *0* (zero) as a result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

=SUM(A1+B1) is actually two operations.  First, the "+" operator sums the two cells:

```
=SUM(20.45)
```

Next, the SUM() function sums the arguments, which now just consist of "20.45"

```
=20.45
```

The correct syntax is either

```
=SUM(A1,B1)
```

or

```
=SUM(A1:B1)
```

which work equally well.  They won't work for you because the DOLLAR() function converts a number to a text value with a specific format.  SUM() does not convert text to numbers, but apparently "+" does.  You may be better served by putting the values of "10.45" and "10" in the cells and formatting them as currency using the "Format Cells" option in the right-click menu.  This will let you use functions on the values, while displaying them as currencies.

Comment: The reason why I am trying the DOLLAR() function is because I have VS Report Designer output a report to excel, and formatting a cell to currency there does not carry over to Excel. I guess my only option would be to keep all cells as numbers and have it be implied that they are dollar amounts.

Comment: Whoops!  Should be =SUM(A1,B1) or =SUM(A1:B1), not =SUM(A1,B1) or =SUM(A1,B1)
Thanks pnuts.

Comment: Mike, how much control do you have over the output of your VS Report Designer or the excel sheet before you get the report?  If you can format the cells beforehand, you can make it appear to be "$10.45"  when the behind-the-scenes value is "10.45"

Comment: The .rdl file from VSRD is uploaded to MS CRM where it is exported to Excel after being filled with CRM data. I pretty much have to do any of the customizations in VSRD because once it's exported to Excel, it becomes used by less-tech savvy people. I tried changing the text box properties of the cells in VSRD to be "currency", but that formatting does not transfer over to Excel. I am guessing that it's because the cells actually hold a formula value rather than a field value. I said "10.45", but the cell's actual value is some long formula. But thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to have a small column with the actual formula without the DOLLAR function. The font is set to White, so that it remains "invisible". This remains numeric/decimal and thus allows the SUM function to work correctly. Then I have another column which is used for Display and that uses the DOLLAR function on the small/white column and has larger font size so that it pops-up.
Note Column H15 and onwards
Attached is a file for reference. [Sample Excel File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZyhNB_i_wRlM03yWQySlfp16QZWiYclVpkIPtH1Zot0/edit?usp=sharing)

NB: The H15 Cell Font is Grey/Gray here to just show the workings.